# How to remove the selected data from the option

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress website, I used to form for sign up page, I used drop down for state and country. I gave all the options. But on the from, it's showing nothing
For your ref,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87pQN.jpg)
But on the options, I have the select your state option and all states.
The options ref,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaH4b.jpg)
I want to remove the nothing on the form, it should show the 1st option. If I inspect the field,
It's shows:

```
<div id="dig_cs_billingstate" class="minput  dig-custom-field dig-custom-field-type-dropdown"><div class="minput_inner">                    <select name="digits_reg_billingstate" class="dropdownstate " data-req="1">
                        <option value="-1" selected="" data-display="-1">Nothing</option><option value="Select your State">---Select your State---</option><option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option><option ....
```

If I remove the selected option -1, it's showing normally. But I don't know where to edit or how to add php code using code snippets. I tried file manager plugin to check, I wasn't able to find this file. Please help me to fix this issue,

Thank you